# Virtualbox Guest memory limitation with 64bit guest on 32bit host?

Tags: memory, virtualbox, 64-bit, ubuntu-10.10

I use Ubuntu 10.10 (32bit) as the host operating system. However I have enabled PAE so I can see the full 8GB of memory installed on my machine.

I use VirtualBox 4.1.8 to create virtual machines which generally works well. I even use 64bit guests without issue. However I'm limited to 3584MB of memory for the guest operating system. I would like to increase this somehow.

Is this the result of the 32bit host? Is there anyway to overcome this? Will I still be limited if I change to a 64bit host? Thanks.

Comment: This also happens to me. Anybody?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need a 64bit host system to use more than 3584 MB memory for virtual machines.